# Custom View using onCreateView in a DialogFragment

Tags: android, user-interface

Been trying to figure this out for a while now:

I'm trying to create a custom dialog using the standard approach shown on the [Dev site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {    
    private OnDialogResultListener mOnDialogResultListener = null;
    public void setOnDialogResultListener(OnDialogResultListener dialogResultListener) {
        mOnDialogResultListener = dialogResultListener;
    }

    public static CustomDialog newInstance(OnDialogResultListener dialogResultListener) {
        CustomDialog frag = new CustomDialog();        
        frag.setOnDialogResultListener(dialogResultListener);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().setTitle(getString(R.string.Dialog_CustomDialog_Title));
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customdialog, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

With the XML being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/white" android:layout_margin="0px" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <EditText android:hint="@string/Dialog.CustomDialog.OldPassword" android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normalMargin" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="textPassword" android:id="@+id/EditText02" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>
    <EditText android:hint="@string/Dialog.CustomDialog.NewPassword" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="textPassword" android:id="@+id/EditText01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>
    <EditText android:hint="@string/Dialog.CustomDialog.RetypePassword" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="textPassword" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/save" android:layout_width="@dimen/normalButtonWidth" android:id="@+id/btn_Custom_save"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/cancel" android:layout_width="@dimen/normalButtonWidth" android:id="@+id/btn_Custom_cancel"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And after creating and showing the dialog, I'm left with:
[image]

The white background has been applied to emphasize the unexpected and unwanted behavior.

Any ideas? I've tried changing width/heights, using weights in a horizontal LinearLayout, setting width/height programatically - all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did come up with a cheap fix, which I would rather not have to use.

Adding a 0px height, 2000dp (some huge number) width view anywhere in the layout causes it to fill the dialog frame.

Answer (score 2):

I found this tricks:
getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.white);

Looks like better solution.

Answer (score 0):

With the DialogFragment the width and height are null.  Create an extra sub view group with fill parent and it should work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/white" android:layout_margin="0px" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
```

.....

Comment: I'll check this once I get around to it and give you credit if it does work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you set attachToRoot = true during inflater.inflate it should show dialog correctly.

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customdialog, container, true);
```

Comment: I'll try to test this (and Sra's) and mark an answer accordingly - the problem is I know longer have access to the code I was working with. But I simple test shouldn't take too long to throw together.

Answer (score 0):

I used a relativeLayout as the root view in my case and it actually filled out the dialog windows.